# How do I compare two arrays with different lengths as efficiently as possible?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to compare a value of the first array to see if it exist in another array. I have two for loops, and it works for smaller array sizes but when I increase the lengths it takes a long time to compile.

```
bool value_check(int arr1[], int arr2[], int nums)
{
    int  value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums; i++)
    {
        value = arr1[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < nums; j++)
        {
            if (value == arr2[j])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use arrays?  Are these sorted?

Comment: No I don't have to use arrays, and not sorted. If it were sorted would it be much faster?

Comment: *If it were sorted would it be much faster?* -- Two words -- *Binary search*.

Comment: If they were sorted you could use [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) which does all the work for you and gives you the common elements.

Comment: Do you understand that your function returns `true` immediately after it finds the first element of `arr1` in `arr2` ?

Comment: @JakeGinobi Yes, the runtime complexity of sorting is _O(n log(n))_ and finding duplicities in sorted arrays takes _O(n)_. Your algorithm is _O(n²)_, which is much worse for longer input arrays.

Comment: And if they are not sorted, create two sets, and check the intersection.

Comment: *when I increase the lengths it takes a long time to compile* I doubt it takes longer to *compile* your code.

Comment: `std::equal` comes to mind. Probably won't be faster than your method, but way more productive.

Comment: @DeiDei `std::equal` would fail for finding `{1,2,3}` in `{1,1,2,2,3,3}`

Comment: The name `value_check` is slightly ambiguous. It looks like the current code returns true if __any__ value in the first array is in the second. Is that the behaviour you're looking for?

Comment: If the arrays are different lengths, why do you treat them as the same length?

Comment: @TimRandall Yeah. Basically like if I see any value that are in both arrays I just want to return true immediately

Comment: unclear what you want, searching for sub-array, intersection-set, contain any value of the second array ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I compare two arrays with different lengths as efficiently as possible?

The usual thing to do is to sort the arrays. Once that's done, comparing is quick because you can step through the two arrays together.

Sorting the arrays can be done in O(n log(n)) time, and comparing them after that only takes O(n) time, so overall you get O(n log(n)) complexity.

Comment: Side note: if arrays are const, even making copies of and sorting these likely is faster for large arrays (solely the point *when* this gets faster is a bit later...). For objects that are expensive to copy: use pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As Caleb notes, it is asymptotically faster to sort the inputs first.

Here's something that uses `std::set_intersection` and still manages to eagerly return.

```
struct Found{};
struct Finder : std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void> // for brevity
{
    Finder* operator->() { return this; }
    Finder& operator*() { return *this; }
    Finder& operator=(int) { throw Found{}; }
    Finder& operator++() { return *this; }
    Finder& operator++(int) { return *this; }
};

bool any_intersection(std::vector<int> lhs, std::vector<int> rhs)
{    
    std::sort(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
    std::sort(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    try { std::set_intersection(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), Finder{}); }
    catch (Found &) { return true; }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using stl, then unordered maps could be more efficient.

Insert the first array into unordered map, then iterate through the second array and lookup into the table to find a match. Return on the first match.

This can be done in O(n)

```
bool value_check(int arr1[], int arr2[], int nums)
{
std::unordered_map<int, int> first;

for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++)
{
    if (!first.count(arr1[i]))
        first[arr1[i]] = 1;
    else
        first[arr1[i]]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++)
{
    if (first.count(arr2[i]) > 0)
    { 
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Since you're only doing key lookups your code could be simpler with `std::unordered_set`. [Example on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/7z636s)